# Lines appearing faint on canvas

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, android-drawable

After creating the drawing below I've noticed that for some reason, some of the black lines appear faintly whereas some of them are clearly visible. What code can be used to ensure that the width of the black lines in-between the grey boxes is exactly 1dp and the width of the red rectangles is exactly 5dp?

[image]

```
public class RectangleTextView extends View {
    private final Paint mBackPaint = new Paint();
    private final Paint mRedPaint = new Paint();
    private int mSideRectWidth = 10;

    public RectangleTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mBackPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        mRedPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    }

    @Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        if (getWidth() == 0)
            return;

        //draw grey boxes
        setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#808080"));
        int boxWidth = getWidth() / 7;

        //draw black line
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            canvas.drawLine(mSideRectWidth + boxWidth * i, 0, mSideRectWidth + boxWidth * i, getHeight(), mBackPaint);
        }

        //draw left end rectangle
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, mSideRectWidth, getHeight(), mRedPaint);

        //draw right end rectangle
        canvas.drawRect(getWidth() - mSideRectWidth, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), mRedPaint);
    }
}
```

Comment: `... to ensure that the width of the black lines in-between the grey boxes is exactly 1dp and the width of the red rectangles is exactly 5dp?` Maybe you're confuse about **px** and **dp**. The `drawXYZ()` methods of the canvas object work in **px**, while you need **dp**, for density independency.

Comment: So, depending on your current density, you should convert the desired **dp**s to **px**s, in order to let the `drawXYZ()` methods use the correct values.

Comment: `mBackPaint.setStrokeWidth(2f);`

Comment: @JoopEggen OK cool. Just to clarify what does the `f` in `2f` mean?

Comment: `2f` is a float 2 ("pixels"). You are seeing the problem that this is not integral. Two to remove the too thin lines, seemed worth a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that the entire way in which you initialize the `Paint` object? I don't know the default values used by the default constructor. I usually set them explicitly: take off the `ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG`, set the style to `Paint.Style.STROKE` and set the desired stroke `width`. Some of the values that you need might be the default ones, I just don't know.

When dealing with thin lines, turning off the `ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG` might be quite important.

Comment: Need to see some code as I've never done that before. I want the thin lines to be 1dp in width exactly.

Comment: int valueInPx = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, <value_in_dp>, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
or 
int valueInPx = getResources().getDimension(resourceID) - for reading from resources
  Paint linePaint = new Paint();
  linePaint.setAntiAlias(false);
  linePaint.setStrokeWidth(valueInPx);
  linePaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);